# flutter overflow never appear in app or devTools but exist

Tags: flutter

In context of desktop flutter application, I have a overflow throw said by my console IDE.

But with these particular points I can't found to resolve this issue.

[image: App screen]

[image: devTools screen]

• the overflow is trigged by NewsContentScreen BUT there is a free space bottom of this

• The only constraint is on MyApp widget that specify 1200 on height size

• My app nothing on running a black/yellow stripes overflow

• The devTools never show black/yellow stripes overflow, I can't find any overflow displayed into devTools

• I never viewed a constraint size height into devTools that corresponding limit of start overflow

• I can't find any overflow displayed into app when it running

• All the parents (expect initialSize of appWindow) have unconstraints/unbounded size

• When the app running you can view :

- it remains a free space bottom the NewsContentScreen widget
- the limit of overflow starting

In this context, I can't find where is the issue and how resolve this.

**Do you have a idea What/where/how Cause/find/Resolve this strange overflow ?**

Comment: Sometime it does not shows in overflow. I think you are getting error in console.